# Building Roslyn and generate PDB files

Tags: .net, roslyn, opencover

Our company needs to generate OpenCover report for all the open source products we are using. One of them is Roslyn compiler. I'm not very good at either Roslyn or OpenCover, but as far as I understand, I need pdb files to generate cover report. The problem is that, the build steps documented [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Building%20Testing%20and%20Debugging) doesn't generate pdb files, even though default build type is set to Debug. So my question is, how do I force pdb file genereration when building Roslyn?

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating full pdbs?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested, the guys from github answered this question [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23467#issuecomment-348015479)

> The PDBs we generate in a local build are embedded. See DebugType
>   setting here:
>   https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/build/Targets/Settings.props#L125
>   You can override DebugType and set it to full to get Windows PDBs. I
>   believe OpenCover currently only supports Windows PDBs.